# How to Enable/Disable Ms-Word Command Button Using Office JS?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js, word-addins

I am creating a word custom add-ins and in that depending on the file name I have to disable and enable custom ribbon button/s or we can say hide/show custom ribbon button/s.

I go through the link given in Microsoft Docs [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands) and many other article that suggest that it is only currently in preview state and only accessible on Excel.

I also go through Office User Voice and found one suggestion [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/15114417-support-for-hiding-showing-task-pane-through-the-o).

If anyone have alternative of this then please help me to achieve that.

**Support**: This add-ins should support ***Word for Windows***,  ***Word For Mac*** and ***Word For Web***.

Answer (score 0):

As you found in the documentation, enable/disable of ribbon buttons is currently only available in Excel. We are currently looking at bringing the capabilities to PPT but I cannot give you a timeline for when to expect enable/disable for Word.

I would suggest adding a comment to the User Voice suggestion regarding compatibility with Word.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. There is already added the suggestion over there from many long time ago. 
Link is given here.[https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/15114417-support-for-hiding-showing-task-pane-through-the-o]
Can you please go through that?